# The jquery code is not executed after a renderJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, fetch

(Sorry for my english )

I realized 3 tabs that dynamically reload my activities, a GET request is made in order to display a specific list of activities (activity of a group / of the user / news)

However I have a jquery code that no longer runs when I click on one of these tabs,
With rails I return a collection to display the activities, a solution remains to put the jquery in this collection, but when I do this the jquery is executed for each activities loaded and is not that i want.

Activities :

```
<div class="activity-card-container" id="activity-cards">
  <%= render partial: 'activities/activity', collection: @activities %>
</div>
```

```
  $('.newness').on('mouseenter', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
          $(this).toggleClass('d-none');
          let num = parseInt($.trim($('.body__activity_counter').html()));
          $('.body__activity_counter').html(--num);
          if (num == 0) {
              $('.body__activity_counter').addClass('hover');
          }
          newnessId = $(this).data('id');
          $.ajax({url: '/user_activities.json', method: 'POST', data: {user_activity: {activity_id: newnessId}}})
      });
```

Partial Activity :

```
<div class="activity--js margin-card activity-card card card-body">
.......
  <%= activity.title %>

  <%= activity.content %>
.......
</div>
```

One of the Tab controller :

```
  def fetch_activities
    user = current_user
    activities = []
    user.groups.each do |group|
      activities << Activity.where(group: group)
    end
    @all_activities = activities.flatten.sort_by(&:updated_at).reverse
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

and his route :

```
  get "/fetch_activities" => 'activities#fetch_activities', as: 'fetch_activities'
```

Thanks

Comment: If you are using turbolinks you need to change this to delegate the handler from the document. `$(document).on(’mouseenter’,  ’.newness’, function(){ ... })`

Comment: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks/blob/master/README.md#making-transformations-idempotent

Comment: Bingo! Thanks man !